# Why does builtin_expect taken in a long instead of a bool?

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, llvm-gcc

I was going through the GCC manual 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

I had the following question about builtin_expect

> long __builtin_expect (long exp, long c)

Why is the exp of long type when the type should have been bool ?

For example:The kernel defines an macro for converting the expression to bool

> define likely(x)  __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)

Then why not define an interface in which exp is bool rather than long ?

Comment: because bool is not in c89 standard

Comment: @amdixon If that's the case, then why didn't they use a `typedef long BOOL`? Apart from that, picking a signed type for bool representation is sloppy practice.

Comment: Why "should" it require a bool? what's wrong with a long?

Answer (score 0):

`__builtin_expect` returns the value of `exp` so for consistency it should return it as the same type as `exp`, too.

The choice of `long` (if it really still is the case and the documentation is not just lacking behind) is probably historical. What I would expect from such a feature is to leave expression `exp` completely unchanged in type and value. This feature should only "annotate" the code with a hint to the compiler and not change the semantic if e.g the type of `exp` would be `unsigned long`.

BTW, the expression `!!(x)` in the kernel macro doesn't have type `_Bool` but is `int`, and that example is just a particular use case where the `exp` only may have two outcomes. The feature itself is more general than that.